# Getting Out Of Memory Error when saving big files

Tags: java, android, file, memory

I'm trying to save file taken by another app into internal directory at background thread with this method :

```
 public static File saveUri(Uri uri,File file, WeakReference<Context> contextWeakReference) throws IOException {

        ContentResolver resolver=contextWeakReference.get().getContentResolver();

        InputStream inputStream=resolver.openInputStream(uri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            stream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        

        fileOutputStream.write(stream.toByteArray());
        fileOutputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        return file ;

    }
```

and it works until I save file like 100 MB size. Above that it gives :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 134217744 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 124MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 95471864, growth limit 201326592
```

at this line :

```
stream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

This is what I use for backround process :

```
public static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor =
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

What should I do for saving big size file without causing Out Of Memory Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but you probably want a append the bytes to the `FileOutputStream` and write the buffer in the loop :

```
public static File saveUri(Uri uri, File file, ContentResolver resolver) {
    try (final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file, true)) {
        final InputStream inputStream = resolver.openInputStream(uri);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error writing file");
    }
    return file;
}
```

There are many ways to do this...

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading from inputStream, you are not writing to the `FileOutputStream` you are saving all the content in memory on the `stream` variable.

Please, link both the streams, so the content of the file you are copying don't stay in memory